# Angular 2 router.navigate()

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I have a serious issue when I am trying to navigate on a different page Angular 2 `router.navigate()`

I have to reload the page each and every time without it, I am not able to load the data with html.. service is running fine and I am getting the data each time when I route to the page need help..

Please suggest me how can I fix it without reloading and if not.

Is there any other trick ?

Don't suggest me `window.location.reload` function..

Help me please

Comment: Share the related code, then it will help to answer.

Comment: that.router.navigate(['/dashboard/featured']); and featured page has some services which load the data  according to user... cannot post code right now because I will have to create a different version..cannot share the original one

Comment: if someone can suggest without it.. will helpfull

Answer (score 0):

if you navigating a page by click on button add (click) function like feature($event)
in your tsfile

```
feature(event)
        {
        this._router.navigate.navigate(['/dashboard/featured']);
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        }
```

Comment: thanks but I am not using on button I am using a function on the button and it contains the above code